# What is the difference between struct format characters L (long) and I (int)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's the difference between i1 and i2 in Python 3?  Why is i1 faster? Is one of the two better?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters

```
import struct, timeit

print("i1 in %s" % timeit.timeit(
    "struct.unpack('<I', b'\\x3C\\x5B\\x01\\x00')",
    globals=globals(), number=10000000))
print("i2 in %s" % timeit.timeit(
    "struct.unpack('<I', b'\\x3C\\x5B\\x01\\x00')",
    globals=globals(), number=10000000))

i1 = struct.unpack('<I', b"\x3C\x5B\x01\x00")[0]
i2 = struct.unpack('<L', b"\x3C\x5B\x01\x00")[0]

print(i1, type(i1), i2, type(i2))
```

Output:

> i1 in 1.336791369 
> i2 in 1.430974416 
> 88892 <class 'int'> 88892 <class 'int'>

Comment: And what can explain the difference in speed?

Comment: I don't get any significant difference when I run this. Try tining it properly, like this: `timeit.timeit("struct.unpack('<I', b'\\x3C\\x5B\\x01\\x00')", globals=globals(), number=10000000)`

Comment: thanks, that give a more accurate result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The labels ‘int’ and ‘long’ found in the `struct` module’s documentation do not refer to the Python type `int` and Python 2 type `long`, but to C types `int` and `long`.  The bit widths of those types depend on the platform ABI; these days, `int` is commonly 32 bits wide, while `long` is usually either 32 or 64 bits wide.

Enabling any of the ‘standard sizes’ options (`<`, `>` or `=`) switches the `struct` module to conform to an [IL32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3325706/3840170) ABI, in which both `int` and `long` are 32 bits wide, and only `long long` is 64 bits wide.  As such, in those modes there is no difference between `I` and `L`, and to pack or unpack a 64-bit value in those modes, the `q` (`long long`) specifier is needed.  However, when operating in the default ‘native sizes’ mode (`@`), the sizes of `I` and `L` may be different.  For example, on my x86-64 Linux system, I get this:

```
>>> struct.pack('@L', 0)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> struct.pack('@I', 0)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

As 64-bit Linux is an [LP64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3325706/3840170) platform, the width of `long` is 64 bits, while the width of `int` is 32 bits.  64-bit Windows, on the other hand, is an LLP64 platform, on which `long` is 32 bits wide.

Comment: Which one should I use in python for int32? <I?

Comment: I usually use `<I`. You may need `>I` sometimes as well (it’s nowhere said everything is little-endian). Though if you happen to be copying the layout from a C struct definition, it’s best to follow it as-is, even if you know the ABI makes `int` and `long` equivalent.